# "Cannot assign requested address" error when connecting to Elasticsearch in .NET Core 6.0 Docker application

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, docker-compose, nest

I'm currently working on a .NET Core 6.0 to utilize `Elasticsearch` for indexing and search functionalities. The application is running inside a Docker container along with Elasticsearch and SQL Server. However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to connect to Elasticsearch from my .NET Core application.

I have a `Docker Compose` file that sets up the services for my application, including Elasticsearch. The Elasticsearch service is defined with the necessary environment variables and volumes. The connection URI for Elasticsearch in my `appsettings.json` configuration file is set to "http://elasticsearch:9200". I have also implemented a custom ElasticsearchClient class to handle the Elasticsearch connection.

When I run the application, it throws the following exception:

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful () low level call on
> GET:
> /_cluster/health?wait_for_nodes=1&wait_for_active_shards=1&timeout=50s
>
> ## Audit trail of this API call:
>
> - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Hx6.png) ProductCheckOnStartup: Took: 00:00:00.0870458
> - [2] ProductCheckFailure: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0777851
>
> ## OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to
>
> an unsuccessful product check call. Some functionality may not be
> compatible if the server is running an unsupported product. Call:
> Status code unknown from: GET /  --->
> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: The client is unable to verify
> that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check
> call. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is
> running an unsupported product.  --->
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address
> (localhost:9200)  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot
> assign requested address    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError
> error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    ...

I believe the issue is related to the connection settings or the way I'm trying to access Elasticsearch from inside the Docker container. I have already checked the following:

The Elasticsearch service is up and running, and the port mapping is correctly set in the Docker Compose file.

[image]

Could someone please help me identify the cause of this issue and provide guidance on how to correctly connect to Elasticsearch from my .NET Core 6.0 Docker application?

Here are the relevant portions of my Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
# ... hidden because too long ...

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.9.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    restart: always
    # depends_on:
    #   - book-store-db
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - elastic

# ... Rest of the Docker Compose file ...

volumes:
  # mssql-data:
  #   driver: local
  elasticsearch-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

And here's the relevant portion of my appsettings.json configuration:

```
{
  "Application": {
    "Elasticsearch": {
      "Uri": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
      "IndexName": "documents"
    },
    "Indexer": {
      "IndexDelay": 10
    }
  },

  // ... Other configurations ...
}
```

Code that creates and initializes the elastic search cluster.

```
public class ElasticsearchClient
{
    private readonly ILogger<ElasticsearchClient> logger;
    private readonly IElasticClient client;
    private readonly string indexName;

    public ElasticsearchClient(ILogger<ElasticsearchClient> logger, IOptions<ElasticsearchOptions> options)
        : this(logger, CreateClient(options.Value.Uri), options.Value.IndexName)
    {

    }

    public ElasticsearchClient(ILogger<ElasticsearchClient> logger, IElasticClient client, string indexName)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.indexName = indexName;
        this.client = client;
    }
    private static IElasticClient CreateClient(string uriString)
    {
        var connectionUri = new Uri(uriString);
        var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(connectionUri);
        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool);

        return new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
    }
}
```

Any help or insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!